# Which one is correct: "get a refund on product" or "get a refund for a product"?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me which one is correct: *get a refund on product* or *get a refund for a product*? For example:

> To get a refund **on** the product your bought, please visit the store you bought it at with the receipt.
>
> To get a refund **for** the product your bought, please visit the store you bought it at with the receipt.

Are both possible? if so, which one is more common? I've gone on the internet to see if there results for both. I found an article with *get a refund on*. I'm not sure if that's a standard and natural use.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Just edited the question.

Comment: "Get a refund for something" is the most usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "correct" preposition for linking the word ***refund*** to whatever previously-sold item is to have its purchase price refunded. But here are [the four most common prepositions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=refund%20for%20it%2Crefund%20of%20it%2Crefund%20on%20it%2Crefund%20to%20it&year_start=1987&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) we might use...

[image]

Personally, I prefer *Can I get a refund **on** [this thing I bought by mistake]?*, but the actual choice isn't really important (I wouldn't be bothered by anyone using ***over, through, from,...***).